# Pandas Transform and add second line between the measurements

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am struggeling with transforming a pandas dataframe.

```
df=
0               A     --    cm
1               B     --   cm2
2               C     69  cm/s
3               D     48  cm/s
4               E    152    ms
5               F   1.05   NaN
6               G   9.15   NaN
7               H     --    ms
8               I      8  cm/s
9               J     12  cm/s
```

I want to transform it to:

```
> A   A_Unit  B    B_Unit  C   C_Unit ...
> --  cm      --   cm2     69  cm/s   ...
```

A to J is a parameter.

Conversion to a dataframe with only numbers works very good with df.T.drop(0), but i have actually no clue, how to add the label of the units it's values next to the parameter columns.

Maybe someone has a good idea and might help me with this topic.

Thanks

Thomas

Comment: What are the header names of df?

Comment: Thanks for your Question. In df there are no header names, only indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stack and transpose since you will always have groupings of two.

---

```
u = df.set_index(0).stack().to_frame().T

u.columns = [
  x if y == 1 else f'{x}_Unit' for x, y in u.columns]
```

```
    A A_Unit   B B_Unit   C C_Unit   D D_Unit    E E_Unit     F     G   H H_Unit  I I_Unit   J J_Unit
0  --     cm  --    cm2  69   cm/s  48   cm/s  152     ms  1.05  9.15  --     ms  8   cm/s  12   cm/s
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+', header=None)

df_out = df.set_index(1).drop(0, axis=1).rename(columns={2:'',3:'Unit'}).stack()
df_out = df_out.to_frame().T
df_out.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' if j else f'{i}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
df_out
```

Output:

```
    A A_Unit   B B_Unit   C C_Unit   D D_Unit    E E_Unit     F     G   H  \
0  --     cm  --    cm2  69   cm/s  48   cm/s  152     ms  1.05  9.15  --   

  H_Unit  I I_Unit   J J_Unit  
0     ms  8   cm/s  12   cm/s
```